# Remote Desktop/RemoteApp manager that saves or autofills passwords

Tags: remote-desktop

I've got a number of Microsoft Remote Desktop and RemoteApp connections with different servers and different username/passwords. 
These are set to disallow storing the password, so I have to type it every time.

Is there a program that

1. allows me to store Remote Desktop and RemoteApp connections in one central place
2. will remember the password even when the server is configured to disallow storing the password

The results of my search so far. Programs that don't do what I want:

- Devolutions Remote Desktop Manager Free: When the server is configured not to allow stored passwords, stored passwords are rejected on login so I have to enter the password anyway. On the plus side, there's a button to put the stored password on the clipboard so at least I don't have to look it up anymore.
- Terminals: When the server is configured not to allow stored passwords, stored passwords are rejected on login so I have to enter the password anyway. Couldn't find a way to configure RemoteApp connections that connect to more than one server.
- Microsoft remote desktop connection manager: cannot import .rdp files
- Multidesk:cannot import .rdp files
- mRemoteNG: cannot open RDP sessions in separate windows, tabbed interface only. Not suitable for RemoteApp.
- RoyalTS: When the server is configured not to allow stored passwords, stored passwords are rejected on login so I have to enter the password anyway.
- RD Tabs: When the server is configured not to allow stored passwords, stored passwords are rejected on login so I have to enter the password anyway. Cannot open RDP sessions in separate windows.

Comment: Sorry, rushing to a meeting, no time to elaborate. TightVNC does that, I am fairly sure

Comment: Forgot to mention: the servers aren't under my control, so can't install a VNC server on them.